# Missing classes of HttpBuilder in Groovy

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

Here is simple request I try to do and watch response

```java
def httpReq = new HTTPBuilder("http://${url}")
        httpReq.request(Method.GET, ContentType.JSON) {

            response.success = { resp ->
                println("Ok  " + resp.status.toString())
            }

            response.failure = { resp ->
                println("Not ok" + resp.status.toString())
            }
```

This returns an Error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.ArrayIterator

I think that ArrayIterator defined in jdk. I added manually `org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Don't waste your time by gathering deps.  Use a build tool like Gradle
or Maven - or use Groovys Grapes if only a script is needed and Groovy
is installed (or easily installable) on your target.

#### Using `grape`

You have to pick up **all** the transitive dependencies (this means the correct packages with the correct versions).  E.g. with `@Grab`:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1')
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')
def html = http.get( path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'] )
```

If you really want to gather all the deps manually `grape` can also
help.  It can tell you, what jars are needed:

```sh
% grape resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.7.1
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/jars/http-builder-0.7.1.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.2.1.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.2.1.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.6.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/jars/json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.4.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/net.sf.ezmorph/ezmorph/jars/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml/jars/nekohtml-1.9.16.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
$HOME/.groovy/grapes/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/jars/xml-resolver-1.2.jar
```

From this list you can build up your own classpath to pass to groovy and
work without grape.  E.g.:

```sh
% cat no-grape.groovy 
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')
def html = http.get( path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'] )

% groovy -cp `grape resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.7.1 | paste -s -d:` no-grape.groovy
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use Groovys Grape but it can't download dependencies with error Error grabbing Grapes [download failed: ...] in Intellij, also I installed groovy and tried to start script via windows cmd like this groovy -Dgroovy.grape.report.download=true MyScript.groovy and have Server access error at url repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/… (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused). But I can get data in browser. Also when I create maven project and add dependencies in pom everything is fine. Is it means that browser and maven are configured with proxy?

Comment: Yes, most likely